# Swagger ApiModelProperty access

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger-2.0

I'm using the same Object both for my Request and Response on a REST endpoint.
Is it possible to annotate a property with **ApiModelProperty(access = "response")**
and then annotate the rest endpoint method with **@ApiImplicitParam(access = "response")**
so that the property only shows up in the swagger doc for the response object and not the request one?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same using `@ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true).`
Allows a model property to be designated as read only. It will hide property from request and shows for a response only.

```
@ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work on swagger 1.6, the property shows up for both request and response when this annotation is applied to a java field.

Answer (score 1):

You better write a new DTO for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with

```
@ApiParam(access = "hidden")
```

Reference:
[Spring Rest API with Swagger – Fine-tuning exposed documentation](https://jakubstas.com/spring-jersey-swagger-fine-tuning-exposed-documentation/#.Woql_oPOVQI)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
@Schema(accessMode=AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use now

```
@ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)
```